# My prettier extension won't work as others do

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm new in coding and had some problems with my **prettier** extension on VSC.

When watching other people use prettire, I noticed that their code will automatically fixed when saving. For example, when forgetting to close a tag`<div>/div>`other peoples code will be fixed to `<div></div>` automatically, when mine doesn't. [image] Showing this error.

I have changed my default formatter from null to esbenp.prettire,format on save, and changed configure default formatter to prettier. What should I do?

Comment: prettier doesn't automatically close a tag however it does formats the code either on save or while writing the code depending upon your settings. Please restart your vscode once to fix this issue

Comment: I have restarted my vscode but nothing has changed! I was asking because I saw a lecture that says that using prettier, will fix your code when it is wrong.